# Error writing file system info: Input/output error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система, lubuntu, initramfs

На нетбуке стоит система - lubuntu 18.04.5 64bit. При резком отключении питания, выключении с кнопки или ещё каких-нибудь форсмажорах, когда нетбук выключается не через "shutdown", при загрузке системы вылезает ошибка "/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY;".[image: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY]

Прописываю fsck /dev/sda1, результат "Error writing file system info: Input/output error".[image: Input/output error]
Нетбук используется только для выхода в сеть, **ценных данных на диске нет**, кроме настроек и chrome.
ВОПРОС: Как сделать, чтобы всё работало, может есть какая-то команда для терминала, которая устраняет ошибки, учитывая что на диске нет ничего ценного(в идеале, сохраняя настройки и chrome), чтобы не переустанавливать систему? Или может посоветуете более стабильную ос для старых/слабых ПК(нетбук: CPU Intel Atom N450 1.66 ghz, 1gb RAM, 250gb)?

Результат проверки диска smartmontools:

```
    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA
Device Model:     WDC WD2500BEVT-00A23T0
Serial Number:    WD-WX81A7060596
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 60054049a
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 23 16:51:57 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enabled.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 6300) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  76) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7037) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       55
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   153   143   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1341
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2026
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       4706
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2015
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       211
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   185   185   000    Old_age   Always       -       47813
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   103   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       40
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Я б предположил, что диск сыплется. Соответственно, проверяйте/ремапьте его через MHDD, предварительно сохранив (вероятно, через LiveCD) данные, которые получится и требуется сохранить. После обработки MHDD — по обстоятельствам: переставить систему с переразметкой диска, продать, подарить, выкинуть.

Comment: А lubuntu тут не может быть виновата? До этого kali linux стояла, всё вроде было нормально.

Comment: Проверил диск через smartmontools(результаты добавил в вопрос), достаточно ли будет такой проверки и можете что-нибудь по результатам сказать?

Comment: Портить диски физически вообще довольно трудно, и вряд ли операционные системы задаются такой целью. Там вон current pending sectors не нуль, возможно, их перезапись поможет. А может, и не поможет. Остальные значения вроде ничего.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Проверил бэдблоки
`lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1 > badsectors.txt
Checking blocks 0 to 244197375
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):                 
done                                                 
Pass completed, 222 bad blocks found. (222/0/0 errors)
`
222 бэдблока нашлось. Что можете сказать, это помойка или можно ещё использовать такой диск?

Comment: @SlavaUkraini, если есть возможность, я бы ни для чего важного не использовал... если использовать, то я бы полностью перезаписал бы диск (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev...`) — это должно вызвать реаллокацию сбойных секторов и последил бы, не увеличиваются ли значения в samrt'е (5,196,197,198) в дальнейшем...  у меня так один диск с ненулевыми значениями в файлопомойке уже много лет крутится...

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же ошибка на виртуалке Proxmox на хранилище thin-LVM. Место на хрнилище кончилось, а в виртуалке еще числилось свободным. fsck находил ошибки, но записать исправления уже не мог. Сделал fstrim на диск виртуалки - и место освободилось и fsck смог фс починить.